# How to set the windows title on a form called in different thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have 2 forms: Form1 and Form2.
In Form1 I open Form2 in a new Thread by clicking on Button1.
I want to set the title of Form2 but I have no Idea how and whetever it is possible. Here is the code from Form1 , Form2 is just an empty Form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim TH As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf FormShow)

    Private Shared Sub FormShow()
        Dim FF As New Form2
        FF.Show()
        Do While FF.Visible
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TH.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        'How to change the Form2 title?
        'I need something like : TH.Form2.Text="NewTitle"?
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I start the code and click on Button1 Form2 will open. But how can I change the window title in Form2 when I press Button2 on Form1? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need Form2 in a different Thread?  What problem are you solving here?  In general, accessing Forms across Threads causing more problems than its worth...

Comment: My app has basically 2 Threads. Thread 1 = a form with "STOP" button. Thread 2 = CPU intensive calculations. So if I click in the form on "STOP" the whole app will quit. What I need here is to get or set some data between processes. If there is a better way I will do it.

Comment: The correct approach is to move the **WORK** (not the Form) onto a different thread.  Do a search for BackgroundWorker() control and you'll get a billion examples.

Comment: So you described the **task** you want to do. What is the **problem** you are trying to solve?

Comment: i have no idea - the problem part is the task of the crazy professor I am working with.  He will write his own calculation script in my software. My software will convert the code to exe and run it using the threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my comment above:

> The correct approach is to move the WORK (not the Form) onto a
>   different thread. Do a search for BackgroundWorker() control and
>   you'll get a billion examples.

It is technically possible to do what you want in your original question, however:

```
Public Class Form1
Public Shared FF As New Form2

    Dim TH As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf FormShow)

    Private Sub FormShow()
        Application.Run(FF)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TH.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Not IsNothing(FF) AndAlso Not FF.IsDisposed Then
            FF.BeginInvoke(Sub(title)
                               FF.Text = title
                           End Sub, New Object() {"Hello"})
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is **NOT** the recoommended approach, though!

Comment: thank you very much, works good. I will also check the BackgroundWorker examples.